# Now to Set value of a struct with the same definition but different name generated by reflection in Go?

Tags: go, reflection, marshalling

I wrote a function to make a type marshalable, so the main idea is to change all types of keys for maps to string. Here's the function:

```
type A struct {
    MA map[int]*B
    MB *B
}

type B struct {
    IB int
}

func GetMarshableStruct(src interface{}) interface{} {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(src)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    kind := t.Kind()
    fmt.Printf("kind %s\n", kind)
    var result reflect.Value
    switch kind {
    case reflect.Map:
        //Find the map layer count
        layer := 0
        cur := t.Elem()
        for reflect.Map == cur.Kind() {
            layer++
            cur = cur.Elem()
        }
        result = reflect.MakeMap(reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf("a"), cur))
        for layer > 0 {
            result = reflect.MakeMap(reflect.MapOf(reflect.TypeOf("a"), result.Type()))
            layer--
        }
        keys := v.MapKeys()
        for _, k := range keys {
            result.SetMapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(fmt.Sprintf("%v", k)), reflect.ValueOf(GetMarshableStruct(v.MapIndex(k).Interface())))
        }
    case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
        result = reflect.MakeSlice(t, v.Len(), v.Cap())
        for i := 0; i < v.Len(); i++ {
            result.Index(i).Set(reflect.ValueOf(GetMarshableStruct(v.Index(i).Interface())))
        }
    case reflect.Ptr:
        result = reflect.New(v.Elem().Type())
        result.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(GetMarshableStruct(reflect.Indirect(v).Interface())))
    case reflect.Struct:
        structFields := make([]reflect.StructField, 0)
        fieldValues := make([]reflect.Value, 0)
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            tmpV := reflect.ValueOf(GetMarshableStruct(v.Field(i).Interface()))
            fieldValues = append(fieldValues, tmpV)
            sf := reflect.StructField{}
            sf = t.Field(i)
            sf.Type = tmpV.Type()
            structFields = append(structFields, sf)
        }
        resultT := reflect.StructOf(structFields)
        result = reflect.Indirect(reflect.New(resultT))
        for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
            fmt.Printf("%s\n", result.Field(i).Type())
            result.Field(i).Set(fieldValues[i])
        }
    default:
        result = v
    }
    return result.Interface()
}

func main() {
    a := new(A)
    a.MA = make(map[int]*B)
    a.MA[4] = new(B)
    a.MA[4].IB = 2
    a.MB = new(B)
    a.MB.IB = 3
    b := GetMarshableStruct(a)
    fmt.Printf("%T %v %T %v\n", a, a, b, b)
}
```

But I got the error:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type struct { MA map[string]*main.B; MB *main.B } is not assignable to type main.A

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4c67c0, 0xc42000a550)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:500 +0x1a1
reflect.Value.assignTo(0xc4200721e0, 0xc42000a540, 0x99, 0x4eb8eb, 0xb, 0x4d4200, 0x0, 0x1, 0xc4200721e0, 0xc42000a540)
        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:2163 +0x35c
reflect.Value.Set(0x4d4200, 0xc42000a3b0, 0x199, 0xc4200721e0, 0xc42000a540, 0x99)
        /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1333 +0xa4
main.GetMarshableStruct(0x4c0ca0, 0xc42000a370, 0x4, 0xc42008e048)
        /home/bzhang/devCodeCore/common/src/go/src/audience/scanner/ref.go:149 +0x12e7
main.main()
        /home/bzhang/devCodeCore/common/src/go/src/audience/scanner/ref.go:114 +0x16a
exit status 2
```

So it seems that when Set() is invoked, the receiver and the parameter must be the same in name? can anyone help with the problem? We can see that the generated struct : struct { MA map[string]*main.B; MB *main.B } is identical to main.A.

Comment: If you haven't notice, `map[string]*main.B` is not identical to `MA map[int]*B` in struct A.

Comment: what if creating a function to change the keys and then assign the values to struct. Rather than setting the value in struct. create an interface with new keys and assign it to struct by type assertion. You just wants to change the keys and then assign to struct or you wants to marshal the struct to create json with new keys. What do you want exactly ?